# Using Wordpress PHP code in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I want to use PHP code in JavaScript. Something like this:

```
function offshownow(){
    document.getElementById("test").src="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'), $plugin_dir; ?>/image.gif"
}
```

What should I do? 
specially it doesn't work !

Comment: As long the file the javascript is in is parsed by PHP, that shouldn't be an issue, did you try it, was there a problem, and what is the question really, "what should I do" is a little to general.

Comment: whats the question, give more details.... errors???

Comment: this code doesn't work :( you mean i wrote the code in the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use WordPress's function `wp_localize_script` in the theme/plugin's PHP code to move the information you need from the server side to the client side. Then, in your JavaScript, refer to that variable that was localised.

Following your barely described use case above, it would be something like...

PHP:

```
wp_enqueue_script("php_vars");
wp_localize_script("php_vars", "php_vars", array(
    "my_url" => get_option('siteurl') . $plugin_dir
));
```

JS:

```
function offshownow(){
    document.getElementById("test").src = php_vars.my_url + "/image.gif";
}
```

You need to do this because JavaScript and PHP are NOT related - JavaScript CANNOT run any PHP code. Over here we've made PHP explicitly push some data over to the JavaScript so it can be used there, but it you can't just do it with `alert("<?php echo "this is awesome :D" ?>");` :(